# Get all available mac id of windows using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, mac-address

I have a working python code to get all available mac id's of windows machines. In my code i'm using subprocess to get all id's and append to a list. I want some alternative to this code which is not using subprocess.

MYCODE:

```
   def mac_list():
        """
        List all Mac id's and store as list
        """
        output = subprocess.check_output("getmac").decode('utf-8')
        regex = r"([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})"
        matches = re.finditer(regex, output)
        listoutputmac = []
        for matchnum, match in enumerate(matches):
            matchnum = matchnum + 1
            listoutputmac.append("{match}".format(matchnum=matchnum, start=match.start(),
                                                  end=match.end(), match=match.group()))
        return listoutputmac
```

- I want exact alternatives to this code any one knows ?